# How to display the previous row and next row from varchar value

Tags: php, mysql

I have hundreds rows of data. I want to get the previous row and the next row from the current item. I saw many examples here but none solve my problem.

My data key is a set of string `(md5)` which is unable to compare the greater or lower like the other does. Here's my resources.

```
---------------------------------------------------
| id|               sid                |   name   |
----+----------------------------------+----------|
| 1 | c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c +  Mr.A    |
----+----------------------------------+----------|
| 2 | eccbc87e4b5ce2fe28308fd9f2a7baf3 |  Mr.B    |
----+----------------------------------+----------|
| 3 | a87ff679a2f3e71d9181a67b7542122c |  Mr.C    |<current position
----+----------------------------------+----------|
| 4 | e4da3b7fbbce2345d7772b0674a318d5 |  Mr.D    |
----+----------------------------------+----------|
| 5 | 1679091c5a880faf6fb5e6087eb1b2dc |  Mr.E    |
--------------------------------------------------|
```

So, is there any way to get the previous row (Mr.B) and the next row (Mr.D) with mysql?

I've tried

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE sid < @sid
ORDER BY sid DESC
LIMIT 1
```

but it's not work because sid is uncomparable.

Comment: Isn't there any `AUTO INCREMENT` primary key in your table?

Comment: And how do you define the `current position`?

Comment: It seems like you're saying there's no way to compare the field that determines previous or next?